# My Ubuntu partition is appearing as full and not allowing me to resize it even when unmounted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, drive, boot-partition

I have Ubuntu installed on a ~500gb boot ssd and I wanted to install a dual boot. I booted into Ubuntu through recovery USB and the yellow bar that indicates free space in your partition was completely full for the Ubuntu partition on my ssd.

Even though I am able to unmount it in the booted gParted, I can't shorten the size at all because it's showing that every bit of space is being used up by ubuntu.

I just installed Ubuntu for school a few weeks ago there is less than 10 gigs of data on the partition. Is this a common issue? And is there any solution besides just reformatting the entire drive? I would really like to be able to install Windows on the same drive without having to reformat the entire partition. Let me know if you guys have any tips!

Comment: Use `df` to find out whether the partition is really full. It is by no means common to have a ~500 Gb root partition, but occasionally some runaway log file fills up all available space. You'll need to find that log file and delete it before you can resize the partition.

Comment: The partition isn't full at all 450 gigs when I check in disks, but when I open gParted it says that the drive is using 476.44 of 476.44 GiB. It really seems like its some sort of bug with my install or gparted I'm just not really sure what to do from here.